# Is there an expression for Jack polynomials in terms of the power sum basis?

Tags: symmetric-polynomials

The Jack polynomials are the 1-parameter family of eigenfunctions of the differential operator:
$$
D_\alpha = \frac{\alpha}{2} \sum_{i} x_i^2 \frac{\partial^2}{\partial x_i^2} + \sum_{i \neq j} \frac{x_i}{x_i - x_j} \frac{\partial}{\partial x_i}
$$
I know that for the Jack polynomial $J_\lambda$,
$$
J_\lambda = m_\lambda + \sum_{\mu < \lambda} c_{\lambda\mu}m_\mu
$$
for some constants $c_{\lambda \mu}$, and where $m_\lambda$ is the symmetric polynomial given by the partition $\lambda$.

Also, for each symmetric polynomial $m_{\lambda}$,
$$
m_\lambda = p_\lambda + \sum_{\mu > \lambda} a_{\lambda \mu} p_\mu
$$
again for some constants $a_{\lambda \mu}$ and where $p_\lambda = p_{\lambda_1} p_{\lambda_2} p_{\lambda_3} \cdots$ is the product of power sums given by the parts of $\lambda$.

So already I can see that the general expression would be quite complicated, as the Jacks are expressed *down* the dominance ordering of partitions with the $m_\lambda$s, but the $m_\lambda$s are expressed *up* the dominance ordering in the $p_\lambda$s

Even in restricted cases of the parameter used to define the Jack polynomials would be good, if there is an easier case. For instance I know that when $0< \alpha < 1$, each $c_{\lambda\mu}$ is a positive integer (rational?).

((Really what I am after is the coefficient on the highest-weighted $p_\lambda$ appearing in the Jack polynomial, so any pointers towards this would be ok too))

Comment: The question is quite interesting to me. It would be even more so with a few examples of decomposition of Jack polynomials in terms of the monomial s.f.

Comment: @WouterM., see the refs in https://tcjpn.wordpress.com/2016/11/27/a-note-on-the-jack-symmetric-functions-polynomials/.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might want to look up Hanlon's conjecture. It is basically gives these "Jack characters" in a quite nice form. 
Also, see [corollary 4.3.1 in here](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1701.05622.pdf), which gives a power-sum expansion of the Jack polynomials.